# CGRectMake's origin arguments don't work

Tags: ios, objective-c

all:
I just started learning ios programming, and I follow the book "IOS programing: Big Nerd Guide programming". In a simple test to create a colorful rectangle block, I have this code:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(160,240,200,150);
    ENTHyposisView *firstView = [[ENTHyposisView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.window addSubview:firstView];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    return YES;
}
```

the ENTHyposisView simply inherits from UIView. The original coordination in CGRectMake, (160,240) seems not working - while the rectangle block did appear with right size and color, the origin is at the (0,0) position rather than the specified one.

The code seems too straightforward to have missed anything, but why it didn't act as expected?

Thats gonna be something I have missed or not aware of.

Thank you all for the help,
john

Comment: I replaced ENTHyposisView with UIView and ran this code.  Worked fine.

Comment: thanks Danh. Your change works. and I took a look at my ENTHyposisView.h, and noticed that i added a property like this:`@property (nonatomic) CGRect frame;`. After removing it, my original code works as expected - i dont know how that property affected the output though.

Comment: by adding a frame property, the subclass overrode the frame behavior that would otherwise be inherited from UIView.